# Build CEF (Chormium) from Source Code error

Tags: chromium, chromium-embedded

I am following the steps to make a build of Chromium from the source code:
https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/docs/windows_build_instructions.md#Install

But when I am at try to "fetch chromium"

I get the error:

```
fetch chromium
Running: 'D:\dev\depot_tools\win_tools-2_7_6_bin\python\bin\python.exe' 'D:\dev\depot_tools\gclient.py' root
Running: 'D:\dev\depot_tools\win_tools-2_7_6_bin\python\bin\python.exe' 'D:\dev\depot_tools\gclient.py' config --spec 'solutions = [
{
"url": "https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src.git",
"managed": False,
"name": "src",
"deps_file": ".DEPS.git",
"custom_deps": {},
},
]
'
Running: 'D:\dev\depot_tools\win_tools-2_7_6_bin\python\bin\python.exe' 'D:\dev\depot_tools\gclient.py' sync
Error: Command 'D:\\dev\\depot_tools\\win_tools-2_7_6_bin\\python\\bin\\python.exe src/build/landmines.py' returned non-zero exit status 1 in D:\dev\chromium
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:\dev\depot_tools\\fetch.py", line 299, in <module>
sys.exit(main())
File "D:\dev\depot_tools\\fetch.py", line 294, in main
return run(options, spec, root)
File "D:\dev\depot_tools\\fetch.py", line 288, in run
return checkout.init()
File "D:\dev\depot_tools\\fetch.py", line 131, in init
self.run_gclient(*sync_cmd)
File "D:\dev\depot_tools\\fetch.py", line 78, in run_gclient
return self.run(cmd_prefix + cmd, **kwargs)
File "D:\dev\depot_tools\\fetch.py", line 68, in run
return subprocess.check_output(cmd, **kwargs)
File "D:\dev\depot_tools\win_tools-2_7_6_bin\python\bin\lib\subprocess.py", line 573, in check_output
raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd, output=output)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '('D:\\dev\\depot_tools\\win_tools-2_7_6_bin\\python\\bin\\python.exe', 'D:\\dev\\depot_tools\\gclient.py', 'sync')' returned non-zero exit status 2
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: before doing so run this from that command line: set DEPOT_TOOLS_WIN_TOOLCHAIN=0. Do you have VS installed? The latest SDK uses VS 2017 so you must have VS installed too. Let me know, if it works

Answer (score 0):

The official documentation on how to build CEF (which also builds Chromium) can be found here:

https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/cef/wiki/MasterBuildQuickStart.md
https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/cef/wiki/BranchesAndBuilding.md

To give you a small idea of what you require:

- Windows 7 or newer, 64-bit OS.
- Visual Studio VS2017 15.3.2+ installed in the default location.
- Windows 10.0.15063.468 SDK installed in the default location. You must install this exact SDK version to avoid build issues.
- At least 8GB of RAM and 40GB of free disk space.

I recommend at least 16GB of RAM, 100 GB disk space (fast SSD), and at least a 4-core CPU. It will still take many hours to build CEF.